# how to use unix date function to calculate quarter of the year

Tags: date, unix, unix-timestamp

In unix, from using the `date` command, I know I can extract information for a given date and for ISO-8601 like so:

```
$ date --iso-8601 -d 20131229
2013-12-29
```

Iso week number:

```
$ date -d 20131229 +%V
52
```

ISO Day of week:

```
$ date -d 20131229 +%u
7
```

Is there a way to calculate quarter of the year?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no date setting to calculate quarter, so you have to do it a bit different way. This is a formula to calculate quarter assuming 1-3 month is the 1st quarter etc.
To calculate the month use:

```
$(date -d 20130129 +%m)
```

Month is zero based so to convert it to a integer use:

```
$((10#$(date -d 20130129 +%m)))
```

Then make number of months zero based in order to calculate zero base quarter:

```
$(($((10#$(date -d 20130129 +%m))) - 1))
```

And then calculate zero based quarter and adjust it to quarter:

```
echo $(($(($((10#$(date -d 20130129 +%m))) - 1)) / 3 + 1))
```

So this is how to do it (and the test as a proof):

```
echo $(($(($((10#$(date -d 20130129 +%m))) - 1)) / 3 + 1))
result:1
echo $(($(($((10#$(date -d 20130228 +%m))) - 1)) / 3 + 1))
result:1
echo $(($(($((10#$(date -d 20130329 +%m))) - 1)) / 3 + 1))
result:1
echo $(($(($((10#$(date -d 20130429 +%m))) - 1)) / 3 + 1))
result:2
echo $(($(($((10#$(date -d 20130529 +%m))) - 1)) / 3 + 1))
result:2
echo $(($(($((10#$(date -d 20130629 +%m))) - 1)) / 3 + 1))
result:2
echo $(($(($((10#$(date -d 20130729 +%m))) - 1)) / 3 + 1))
result:3
echo $(($(($((10#$(date -d 20130829 +%m))) - 1)) / 3 + 1))
result:3
echo $(($(($((10#$(date -d 20130929 +%m))) - 1)) / 3 + 1))
result:3
echo $(($(($((10#$(date -d 20131029 +%m))) - 1)) / 3 + 1))
result:4
echo $(($(($((10#$(date -d 20131129 +%m))) - 1)) / 3 + 1))
result:4
echo $(($(($((10#$(date -d 20131229 +%m))) - 1)) / 3 + 1))
result:4
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks for showing that to me.